# How to pick up variable in mysql.query callback function

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, callback

```
global.games = {};

let sql = /* some Sql */;
connection.query(sql, function(err, results) {
   /* results must be parsed and stored in global.games, but I can see them only inside this function*/

});
```

How can I get the results outside callback?

Comment: Where you want to see your result?

Comment: results must be parsed and stored in global.games

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Dude, where you have written the code to push your result in global.games? and what are your results type it's object or array?

Comment: I realized the problem))) mysql driver do async queries))

Answer (score 0):

You can add response object to JavaScript global object `window`

```
window.global.games = {};

let sql = /* some Sql */;
connection.query(sql, function(err, results) {
    window.global.games = results;
});
```